# Unity for MVC5 in NuGet

Tags: unity-container

I want to use Unity for MVC 5. I found this Link:- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-ioc-using-unity-in-mvc-5/

I don't find Unity Bootstrapper for MVC5 in NuGet. What would be its equivalent ?

I think what I am looking for is Unity Application Block for MVC5.

I need these following libraries which would be compatible with MVC5:-

1. Microsoft.Practices.Unity
2. Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration
3. Microsoft.Practices.Unity.MVC
4. Microsoft.Practies.Unity.RegistrationByConvention

Which Package from NuGet should I download ??

Answer (score -1):

The [ownership changed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/) after version 4.01. There have been namespace changes and possibly some API changes but it works with MVC 5.

The packages you need are

- [Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/5.6.1)
- [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/5.0.12)
- and possibly [Unity.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/)

Most of documentation and articles on the web is for version 4. If this is your first time working with a DI container you may want to use the 4.01 version so you can follow along with those online resources.